# Android Camera2 - Remove black space between camera and bottom bar

Tags: android, android-camera2

I'm trying to develop an application that uses Camera 2 API, but I have a problem when I try to edit the height of the bottom bar. I would like to remove the black space between the camera and bottom bar. Moreover, I would like to extend the camera height.

I followed the Google [Camera2Basic](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic) example.

[image]

Could I fix this problem?

Thanks.

**activity_camera.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000"
    tools:context=".CameraActivity" />
```

**fragment_camera2.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:foreground="?selectableItemBackground" >

    <widgets.AutoFitTextureView
        android:id="@+id/texture"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/control"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:paddingBottom="12dp"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:paddingTop="12dp"
        android:background="@color/white" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/picture"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/ic_camera"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/ic_camera"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/cam_circle_selector"
            android:contentDescription="@string/description_info"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_action_capture" />

    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: please provide the xml code.

Comment: I just added the XML code.

Comment: adjust the padding_top in the FrameLayout

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to add more padding

Comment: I was actually asking you to decrease padding. set it to 2 dp and see if it helps. cant compile your code, as i am without android studio right now.

Comment: If I decreased it, I have a higher black space.

Comment: any solution for this!!

Answer (score -1):

You can add the Actionbar back which will cause your camera_view getting a little lower and remove the black divider. In styles.xml, replace this line

```
<style name="MaterialTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen" />
```

with

```
<style name="MaterialTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light" />
```

If you don't want to add Actionbar, you may have to modify AutoFitTextureView or Camera2BasicFragment class.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I prefer to modify Camera2BasicFragment class.

Comment: what to modify but!!

Comment: @BigNick Did you manage to find a solution for this? Can you please share how to do it?